# VT-d support enabled but IOMMU groups are missing

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, pci-passthrough, iommu

On a [Supermicro A2SDi-8C+-HLN4F](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/atom/A2SDi-8C_-HLN4F.cfm) Atom C3758 system I see that VT-d support is enabled in the BIOS but I can't find any IOMMU groups under Linux (Fedora 31):

```
$ ls /sys/kernel/iommu_groups
$
```

The kernel logs seem to indicate that VT-d is detected:

```
# journalctl -k | grep 'DMAR\|iommu' | sed 's/^.*kernel: //'
ACPI: DMAR 0x000000007E1629C0 000070 (v01 INTEL  BDW      00000001 INTL 00000001)
DMAR: Host address width 39
DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x1
DMAR: dmar0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 1:0 cap d2008c40660462 ecap f050da
DMAR: RMRR base: 0x0000007f0fa000 end: 0x0000007f10afff
DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 2 under DRHD base  0xfed90000 IOMMU 0
DMAR-IR: HPET id 0 under DRHD base 0xfed90000
DMAR-IR: Queued invalidation will be enabled to support x2apic and Intr-remapping.
DMAR-IR: Enabled IRQ remapping in x2apic mode
iommu: Default domain type: Translated
```

Do I need to configure something such that I also get IOMMU groups?

Background: I'm looking into this because I can't bind an ethernet device to vfio-pci for dpdk:

```
# /usr/share/dpdk/usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --bind=vfio-pci 07:00.0
Error: bind failed for 0000:07:00.0 - Cannot bind to driver vfio-pci
# /usr/share/dpdk/usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status        

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:05:00.0 'Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE 15e4' if=eno1 drv=ixgbe unused=vfio-pci *Active*
0000:05:00.1 'Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE 15e4' if=eno2 drv=ixgbe unused=vfio-pci 
0000:07:00.1 'Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE 15e4' if=eno4 drv=ixgbe unused=vfio-pci 

Other Network devices
=====================
0000:07:00.0 'Ethernet Connection X553 1GbE 15e4' unused=ixgbe,vfio-pci
# dmesg | tail -n 3
[  +0.169963] ixgbe 0000:07:00.0: complete
[  +0.000561] vfio-pci: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -22
[  +0.000040] vfio-pci: probe of 0000:07:00.0 failed with error -22
```

Comment: Have you loaded kernel with `intel_iommu=on` parameter?

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk, no. You mean that IOMMU isn't on by default under Linux?

Comment: Indeed looks like it, the Fedora kernel config has: `# CONFIG_INTEL_IOMMU_DEFAULT_ON is not set`.

Comment: Yes, IOMMU should be enabled by hand.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk, if you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `intel_iommu=on` to kernel load parameters. By default this parameter is disabled (I don't know distro which set this parameter to `on` by default).

When you've enabled IOMMU in BIOS, then ACPI table translates to kernel DMARs and kernel init this duruing the boot.

When you've set `intel_iommu=on`, then kernel divide system hardware resources into IOMMU groups. It's quantity and granularity depends on hardware. See [VFIO - "Virtual Function I/O"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vfio.txt) for details.

Comment: Can confirm, Fedora has the kernel option `CONFIG_INTEL_IOMMU_DEFAULT_ON` disabled, thus IOMMU is disabled by default. Thus, after booting with `intel_iommu=on` the `/sys/kernel/iommu_groups` directory is populated and the `dpdk-devbind.py --bind=vfio-pci ` call succeeds.